# Aligning label for multiple select in center of select box

Tags: html, css

this is my html page 
[image]

In the above picture, I want label client to be in center of select box. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/n6dNR/2/

```
label,select {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```